# How can I normalize a colormap in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, normalization, colormap

I've made a colormap from a matrix (matrix300.txt). I would like to normalize my colormap, but I don't know how to do it. The axes should be from 0 to 3.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.colors as colors

p = np.loadtxt('matrix300.txt')

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['yellow', 'white'], name='Gamma=1')

bounds = [-1, 0, 1]

norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)

img = plt.imshow(p, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

plt.colorbar(img, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds)

plt.xlabel("h_0")

plt.ylabel("h")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing `bounds = [-1, 0, 1]` to something else?

Comment: Instead of `colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, cmap.N)` you could try `color.Normalize(0, 3)` together with `plt.imshow(p*2 + 1.5, ....)`.

Comment: I've tried, but didn't work.

Comment: You specified `["yellow", "white"]` for `ListedColormap`. That's why your colormap only shows yellow and white.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `ListedColormap` is not right here. It is for creating a user-defined colormap. So it may be a bit too much of elaborating if you need a colormap just for plotting. I post an example using `ListedColormap` anyway.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# dummy data
yy, xx = np.mgrid[0:1:10j, 0:1:10j]
p = np.exp(-10*(xx-0.5)**2-10*(yy-0.5)**2) # gaussian function

# create your own colormap
pmax, pmin = np.max(p), np.min(p) # get data range
bounds = np.linspace(pmin, pmax, 100) # set data range for colormap
num = 100 # how many colors do you need?
norm = colors.BoundaryNorm(bounds, ncolors=num) # an object for cmap normalization
carray = np.array([np.linspace(0,1,num), np.linspace(0.0,0.25,num), [0.5]*num, [1]*num]).T # list of RGBA values
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(carray, N=100, name='mycolormap') # create your own color map from carray

# plot data
img = plt.imshow(p, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(img, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, boundaries=bounds)

plt.show()
```

[image: ex1]

Mush easier way is to use `pcolormesh`.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_aspect("equal")
im = ax.pcolormesh(xx, yy, p, vmin=pmin, vmax=pmax)
cbar = fig.colorbar(mappable=im)
plt.show()
```

[image: ex2]